# Enabling Java8 DateTime API support in SpringBoot breaks Jackson DateTime serialization capability

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, jackson

I have a requirement to accept LocalDate in Spring `@PathVariable` and also to return LocalDate and LocalDateTime as TimeStamps in Response JSON.

I got this error when I tried LocalDate in PathVariable

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.time.LocalDate] for value '2019-12-12'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2019-12-12]
```

I've found multiple solutions(annotating fields with @DateTimeFormatter etc) to solve this but chose the below one as it looked simple and global(I have multiple controllers which accepts LocalDate as `@PathVariable`)
so I've used the following config to enable Java 8 DateTime API support for `@PathVariable`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```

This solved the above mentioned problem but created a new one, it broke JSR-310 support for FasterXML Jackson

Now all my response JSONs looks like this

```
{
  "localDate": [
    2019,
    2,
    6
  ]
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong...any help on this please?

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, It worked, I remember adding it for SwaggerUI support, any explanation or reference please.

Comment: Adding `@EnableWebMvc` will lead to Spring Boot not doing its own autoconfiguration of the Web related infrastructure, because it assumes you do everything. This also leads to not adding some additional defaults to Jodatime for serializing date related information.

Comment: depending on your jackson version this is the supported way from jackson iteself to enable LocalDate support in java 8 https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8